# what is the use of "group by tablename.*" in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

When I have group by users2.* in the below query it does not give error. It gives error only when I try to select column "name". So all columns from users2 table are not included for group by?

```sql
Create table If Not Exists Users2 (user_id int, name varchar(30));
Truncate table Users2;
insert into Users2 (user_id, name) values ('1', 'Daniel');
insert into Users2 (user_id, name) values ('2', 'Monica');
insert into Users2 (user_id, name) values ('3', 'Maria');
insert into Users2 (user_id, name) values ('4', 'James');

-- below query gives
-- SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "users2.name" must appear in the 
-- GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
select users2.name
from users2
group by users2.*
;

-- whereas below queries work correctly
select 1
from users2
group by users2.*
;

select users2."name"
from users2
group by users2.user_id,users2."name"
;
```

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WT50jj6i) for online testing.

Expected behavior:
I expected first query to pass, or get error directly saying the group by tablename.* is not allowed

Comment: I suspect that `group by users2.*` is treated as `group by (users2.user_id, users2.name)` not `group by users2.user_id, users2.name`.

Comment: @Bergi I am new to postgres, what is the difference between "group by (users2.user_id, users2.name)" and "group by users2.user_id, users2.name"? Tried 2 queries with group by with and without brackets, didn't see any difference in the results.

Comment: I betting it is down to,  from [Group By](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY): *In case of ambiguity, a GROUP BY name will be interpreted as an input-column name rather than an output column name.* When you run the query as an `ORDER BY` it works, where *If an ORDER BY expression is a simple name that matches both an output column name and an input column name, ORDER BY will interpret it as the output column name. This is the opposite of the choice that GROUP BY will make in the same situation*

Comment: There is no practical difference between n "group by (users2.user_id, users2.name)" and "group by users2.user_id, users2.name" per [Composite values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I meant that the tuple expression might be handled differently wrt the "*column "users2.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause*" error? Because it doesn't, only the whole `user2` composite value appears. But sure, they'd lead to the same grouping.

Answer (score 1):

I think it comes down to syntax.When you want to use `GROUP BY` you need to be specific on which rows you want to group. For example:

```
select *
from users2
group by users2.*
```

This query also return the error :`users2.name must appear in the Group By clause`